# How to bind the 'Selected' property for a UIButton in MvvmCross

Tags: uibutton, mvvmcross, selected

I have a weird thing. On the Simulator iOS 10.3. the following code works just fine.

```
    set.Bind(Circle1).For("Selected").To(vm => vm.PincodeCircles[0].Activated);
```

On my iPad Pro 12.9 I get an error saying the following:

*[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  2.68 Failed to create target binding for binding Selected for PincodeCircles[0].Activated*

I've already tried the following:

```
    set.Bind(Circle1).For(button => button.Selected).To(vm => vm.PincodeCircles[0].Activated);
```

and gives the same error:

*[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  4.27 Failed to create target binding for binding Selected for PincodeCircles[0].Activated*

Activated is defined as follows on the viewmodel:

```
    public bool Activated
    {
        get { return this._activated; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._activated, value); }
    }
```

The Cirle1 button is of type UICircleButton. Here's the class:

```
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace NN.Plugin.Utils.iOS
{
    public partial class UICircleButton : UIButton
    {
        public UICircleButton(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            Layer.BorderWidth = 2;
        }

        public nfloat BorderWidth
        {   get
            {
                return Layer.BorderWidth;
            }
            set
            {
                Layer.BorderWidth = value;
            }
        }

        public CGColor BorderColor
        {
            get
            {
                return Layer.BorderColor;
            }
            set
            {
                Layer.BorderColor = value;
            }
        }

        public nfloat PointSize
        {
            get => Font.PointSize;
            set => Font = Font.WithSize(value);
        }

        public override CGRect ContentRectForBounds(CGRect rect)
        {
            var newRect = base.ContentRectForBounds(rect);

            Layer.CornerRadius = newRect.Width / 2;

            return newRect;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Selected is a property on UIButton?

Comment: Yes it is. UICircleButton derives UIButton

Comment: Very strange. After adding: 'Circle1.Selected = false;' before the set.Apply() made the binding kick in for some reason. Looks like a bug in MvvmCross. Mind you, I only had to set Selected = false for 1 button for the binding to start working for all buttons!

Comment: Do you have the Linker enabled? In such cases, you need to add additional entries in LinkerPleaseInclude.cs to hint the linker that something is being used, this is due to bindings using Reflection and not directly invoking and assigning methods and properties.

Comment: Aah, right, that could be it! After adding the Selected = false the linker recognizes it has to link the property.

Comment: Why didn't the 'set.Bind(Circle1).For(button => button.Selected).To(vm => vm.PincodeCircles[0].Activated);' do the trick?

Comment: It won't be enough of a hint to preserve the setter for that property I guess. There is no direct assignment of the Selected property.